# matplotlib scatter plot legend click to toggle set visibility

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, legend

I'm trying to make a matplotlib plot which legend can be toggled to select visibility.
If I click certain legend, clicked legend should be faded and corresponding plot should be invisible. If clicked again, it will be restored to its original state.
But following code not work well. If I click legend '10'. This action can be sensed but hiding related figure don't work. Please give some advice.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as canvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np


class MplCanvas(canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super().__init__(fig)



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        df = pd.DataFrame({
        "X" : [1,2,3,4,5], 
        "Y" : [1,2,3,4,5], 
        "pitch":[10,10,20,20,30],
        })
        layout_main = QVBoxLayout()

        # define scatterplot
        self.sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        color = cm.jet
        u, div = np.unique(df.pitch.values, return_inverse=True)
        colorlist = [colors.rgb2hex(color(i)) for i in np.linspace(1, 0, len(u))]
        cmap = ListedColormap(colorlist)        
        
        self.scatter = self.sc.axes.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'] , c=div, cmap=cmap)
        legend = self.sc.axes.legend(self.scatter.legend_elements(prop='colors', num=len(colorlist))[0], u, loc=2)
        l1, l2, l3 = legend.get_lines()
        
        l1.set_picker(True)
        l1.set_pickradius(10)
        
        self.scatter.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)        
        
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.sc, self)
        
        layout_main.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout_main.addWidget(self.sc)
        

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout_main)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
     
            
    def on_pick(self, event):
        print('legend picked.')
        picked_legend = event.artist
        isVisible = picked_legend.get_visible()

        self.scatter.picked_legend.set_visible(not isVisible)
        

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an error: `self.scatter` does not have any attribute called `picked_legend`, on the other hand you must call the draw method of the canvas so that the painting is refreshed.

```py
def on_pick(self, event):
    picked_legend = event.artist
    is_visible = picked_legend.get_visible()
    picked_legend.set_visible(not is_visible)
    self.scatter.figure.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks. But clicked legend would not vanish. Additionally,  I want to make relevant plot vanish too.

Comment: @BrianKim ok so i understood only that it didn't work so "picked_legend" is not the right path. I only have one doubt, let's say that when you click the legend and the corresponding items are hidden, where should you click to make it visible?

Comment: I referenced this from https://learndataanalysis.org/source-code-how-to-toggle-graphs-visibility-by-clicking-legend-label-in-matplotlib/ But i have no idea about how to implement  this to scatterplot.